# jquery selector in selector roof

Tags: jquery, selector

i want to use 2 selector

first selector, i get some value( checked-p ). it is changed .

and second seletor, i want to pass a variable to other page.

but , if i click first selector 4 times. second seletor pass varibles 4 time.

help me please. bottom i past jquery script

```
<script>
    $( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
      var checked_p=$( "input:checked" ).val();

      $(".checked").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checked.php",
    data: "checked_p="+ checked_p, 
    cache: false,
    });

      });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to bind click event for `$(".checked")` everytime you click on `$( "input" )`, this will unecessary bind multiple click event. Hence you are getting multiple values for `$(".checked")` click.

You can save the `$( "input:checked" ).val();` in global variable and use it for `$(".checked")`. And bind click event for `$(".checked")` out side click event of `$( "input" )`. This way you can send latest `checked_p` value.

See below code

```
<script>
    var checked_p='';

    $( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
      checked_p=$( "input:checked" ).val();
    });

    $(".checked").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checked.php",
                data: "checked_p="+ checked_p, 
                cache: false,
              });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: did my solution help you to solve your problem or you did it on your own?

Comment: your solution help me. i did not kown global and local variable. thank you

Comment: great :). You can accept my answer by clicking check mark (which is present below zero with up/down images on the left side of answer) and also upvote it.

Comment: i want. but there are need 15 reputation... i have only 1 reputation.. sorry